# How to handle / endes url to monoserv with nginx?

Tags: asp.net, mono, nginx

I use directly .net (with monoserv and monorail) to make my url rewriting. 
But for that I need to activate wildcard url I made it with IIS and I had no problems.

How is it possible with nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found :

I replaced

```
 location / {
                 root /var/www/;
                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         }
```

by

```
 location ~* ^.+(.rails|/)$ {
                 root /var/www/;
                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         }
```